# Running the unit test class causes error while running the test case independently will success

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a very simple view model class with one function, which basically calls and API and if success will show data while show error state if the API fails

Here is the code for my ViewModel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.williamtan.practice.data.base.NetworkResponse
import com.williamtan.practice.data.model.NewsDetailResponse
import com.williamtan.practice.data.model.UiState
import com.williamtan.practice.domain.usecase.NewsUseCase
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val newsUseCase: dagger.Lazy<NewsUseCase>
): ViewModel() {

    private val _newsList = MutableLiveData<List<NewsDetailResponse>>()
    val newsList: LiveData<List<NewsDetailResponse>> = _newsList

    private val _state = MutableLiveData<UiState>()
    val state: LiveData<UiState> = _state

    fun getTopStories() {
        _state.value = UiState.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val response = newsUseCase.get().getNewsList()) {
                is NetworkResponse.Error ->
                    _state.postValue(UiState.Error(response.errorMessage))
                is NetworkResponse.Success -> {
                    _newsList.postValue(response.result)
                    _state.postValue(UiState.Finished)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to make the UT for this VM, is works if I run each test cases independently, but fails when I run the test class, I am wondering if I make a mistake in the @before or anything

```
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import com.williamtan.practice.data.base.NetworkResponse
import com.williamtan.practice.data.model.NewsDetailResponse
import com.williamtan.practice.data.model.UiState
import com.williamtan.practice.domain.usecase.NewsUseCase
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock

class MainViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var useCase: NewsUseCase

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        useCase = mock(NewsUseCase::class.java)
        val useCaseLazy = dagger.Lazy { useCase }
        viewModel = MainViewModel(useCaseLazy)
    }

    @Test
    fun `show loading and then result on success`() = runBlocking {
        val news = NewsDetailResponse("", 0, 0, 0, "", "")
        `when`(useCase.getNewsList()).thenReturn(NetworkResponse.Success(listOf(news)))

        viewModel.getTopStories()

        val stateCaptor = mutableListOf<UiState>()
        viewModel.state.observeForever { stateCaptor.add(it) }
        assertThat(stateCaptor[0]).isEqualTo(UiState.Loading)
        assertThat(stateCaptor[1]).isEqualTo(UiState.Finished)
        assertThat(stateCaptor.size).isEqualTo(2)

        val newsListCaptor = mutableListOf<List<NewsDetailResponse>>()
        viewModel.newsList.observeForever { newsListCaptor.add(it) }
        assertThat(newsListCaptor[0]).isEqualTo(listOf(news))
        assertThat(newsListCaptor.size).isEqualTo(1)
    }

    @Test
    fun `show loading and then error on failed`() = runBlocking {
        val errorMessage = "errorMessage"
        `when`(useCase.getNewsList()).thenReturn(NetworkResponse.Error(errorMessage))

        viewModel.getTopStories()

        val stateCaptor = mutableListOf<UiState>()
        viewModel.state.observeForever { stateCaptor.add(it) }
        assertThat(stateCaptor[0]).isEqualTo(UiState.Loading)
        assertThat(stateCaptor[1]).isEqualTo(UiState.Error(errorMessage))
        assertThat(stateCaptor.size).isEqualTo(2)

        val newsListCaptor = mutableListOf<List<NewsDetailResponse>>()
        viewModel.newsList.observeForever { newsListCaptor.add(it) }
        assertThat(newsListCaptor.size).isEqualTo(0)
    }
}
```

The error is index out of bound

> Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length
> 1

for the line of:

```
assertThat(stateCaptor[1]).isEqualTo(UiState.Finished)
```

I am testing using Google Truth, Mockito, and JUnit

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong here?